# IdentityServer4 + Docker: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: docker, ssl, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm following the Quickstart guides of IdentityServer4 for the setup of a protected API and accessing it with a client ([Sample 2](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html)). I'm using .Net Core + Docker for Windows (Windows Containers) to run my test application.

The setup should be something like this:

[image]

When I call `https://<identity-url>/.well-known/openid-configuration`, I get the configuration but with the known "not safe - are you sure" page up front.

The `API 1` is secured with:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "https://<identity-url>";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = this.Environment.IsProduction();
            options.ApiName = "api1";
        });
```

and the `Config.cs` (in `IdentityServer`) is according to the documentation of the quickstart.

**Problem:**

When I try to call `API 1` from my `Client` I need to access `IdentityServer` first (according to the quickstart) with:

```
var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("https://<identity-url>");
if (disco.IsError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(disco.Error);
    return BadRequest(disco.Exception);
}
```

This results in this error

> The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation
>   procedure.

I'm using the default certificates from the `.net core templates for web applications` and I think the problem has something to do with the fact, that the certificate is self-signed. Is this correct?

What is the correct way to trust the self-signed certificate in the other container so that a connection can be established?

Comment: add your self signed cert to the truststore in your other docker (@see B.3 http://docs.jboss.org/teiid/7.1.0.Final/client-developers-guide/en-US/html/appendix-selfcerts.html)

Comment: But how to do this in Docker and .net core. I'm not using Java.

Comment: here you can find the list of corresponding powershell commands: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zxue/2016/12/19/adding-https-support-to-individual-windows-containers-using-self-issued-certificates/

Answer (score 1):

You can add de certificate for your container, but this is only available for external request, between containers the certificate you get the error **The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure** because is not posible validate the certificate, the docker network is safe and you can overrides the policy to allow http insted https

the package **IdentityModel** has the extension method **GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync** with overload to add the policy to allow http

```
    DiscoveryDocumentResponse disco = 
    await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(new DiscoveryDocumentRequest { 
                    Address = "http://<identity-url>", 
                    Policy = { RequireHttps = false } 
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with a Web Api and Swagger as client. It's not an identity Server problem but an SSL restriction. If you want to use SSL and https connection to your Ids4 on a remote server, the only way is to buy a certificate from a CA. Putting the self signed certificate in the trust store will also not work. You can use http protocol instead but, of course, just for test purposes.

Comment: I disagree. You can use a self signed certificate with home made CA without any problem. Just add the CA cert to the trusted store.